# ORACLE APEX Region footer text page item accessing inside page process

Tags: oracle, html-table, oracle-apex-5

I have created a custom page item 'tot_credit' to get correct alignment below my tabular form report,  using the below code .
,it is written in the region 'footer text'.But I am unable to access this item 'tot_credit' inside my page process(pl/sql code). It is accessible in java script code. what is the solution?

```
<table>
<tr>
<label>Total Credit</label> <input type="text" style="text-align:right;width:120px"  name="tot_credit" id="tot_credit" >
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adding as answer as I can't add comments yet. Yon need to define an apex page item and use layout property such that your item is declared before your plsql process. I see that you aren't really using apex page items, is that correct?

Comment: ya.. It was not an apex page item, it was defined inside HTML tr. any way the doubt is solved from jeff.. thanx for the response sejal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the item in PL/SQL because you have not defined the item in Apex. You need to define it as an Apex page item, instead of just writing the raw HTML for it.

Comment: Thanx jeff.. actually It was an alignment problem that y I used html item. now I adjusted the width of the item so that aligning is no more a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not able to access it as the item is declared in page footer, and your pl/sql code is defined before the item declaration. Either moving the item declaration upwards on the page, or defining the pl/sql code in page footer - one of these two should solve your problem.

Comment: It is not in the page footer, it is defined at region footer text.. are those same sejal ?.if I move this item definition upward, it will affect the item position.. My page process executes at point "after submit"..